# Accessing a WebService on LocalHost

Tags: android, .net, web-services, web

Does anyone know how to set up any type of web service on your local host and access it from android? Any good tutorials for this. Preferable a .NET web service.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the environment, it seems that adding your dev machine to a local DNS service for a Wifi network, opening up the right ports, and having the Android device connect to that WiFi network where it picks up the DNS server address via DHCP and thus can resolve your machine address is the best general purpose local solution pattern outside of using the emulator/debugger tool chain.

How about using the Windows Azure Service Bus relay? That allows you you to expose a public web service from your dev box to the public Internet and the Android device could even talk to it via 3G.

[Here are all the basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706736) including how to sign up and make a namespace and [here's how to expose an HTTP service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706772.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I put here a list of sites that have helped me to understand better how to create and consume WS:

[link1](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/03/03/how-to-consume-web-services-from-android-applications-using-ksoap2/)

[link2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9EowBVgwSo)

[link3](http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/webservicecallfromandroid/)

[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598734/webservice-soap-in-android)

I hope these helps you...